# open json file from google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a json file in my google drive that i would like read from a google sheet.
I opened the script editor in my sheet and added the following function:

```
function jsonTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1PpnL26_gx3v_sLEkOjnlyIaEIs8FE1ah');
  var body = doc.getBody().getText()
  return body.length
}
```

when i call it in my sheet i get an error. The console tells me, that i am missing the permission, but i added it to my manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
  ]
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As you mentioned, you `have a json file` on your `google drive`. However, I would like to confirm how the file is saved to it. Are the contents stored in a Google Document, or are they saved as a JSON file? I noticed that your script uses [Class DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) which is why I'd like to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function jsonTest() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('id');
  var body = doc.getBody().getText()
  Logger.log(body.length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

What you're doing won't work since you're using a custom function. As per [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> If your custom function throws the error message `You do not have permission to call X service.`, the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

> To use a service other than those listed above, create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

To resolve this, you can follow what's recommended in the documentation or simply try something like this:

```
const jsonTest = () => {
  var documentBody = DocumentApp.openById('1PpnL26_gx3v_sLEkOjnlyIaEIs8FE1ah').getBody().getText();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1').setValue(documentBody);
}
```

This code would get the body of your Google Document which contains your `JSON` file and paste its values on your specified cell in the sheet.

You may also follow @[Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091)'s approach, by using [`console.log();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#log) or [`Logger.log();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata), you'll be able to see the `JSON` in your `Execution log` of Google Apps Script.